# Possible to use Node like PHP for interfacing between website and SQL db?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, node.js

I have a [site](http://mechanicalscribe.com/) that runs on Apache + Jekyll. I'm very happy with this static page setup, since I need something low maintenance.

I'll occasionally run a little survey or game in which I record users' responses to a questionnaire in a SQL database (usually SQLite, but that's immaterial). I use PHP to accept GET or POST ajax requests from a static page and write the parameters to a DB.

I would love to be able to use Node for this, since I use it much more frequently for other projects and am much more comfortable there. (It's maddening to have to relearn PHP once every other month.) I understand how one would accomplish this from the ground up. But I'd really prefer to keep the site running on Apache for all static pages and not mess around with serving them with Node. I love that I can simply upload a PHP page to a directory and have a working server-side script at that URI.

Is there any way to create this same setup with Node, where a Node script received an HTTP request from a page at a certain URL, writes some stuff to a DB, and returns a callback? While leaving the rest of the site untouched?

Comment: Yes you can run apache and node side by side, https://gist.github.com/stagas/754303

Comment: Yes, that works like a charm. You may need this: https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql